# How to make two forms receive information from the serial port that receives information from Arduino?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am developing a graphical interface that reads variables from different sensors that arrive through the serial port, so far I have managed to read all the variables with a single form but now I want to have two forms.

The first form asks the user to choose the COM and confirms whether the connection was successful or not. Once the connection is successful, the second form is opened where the variables from the sensors will be shown in "labels", the readings sent from Arduino are read by the serial port and stored in an array:

> data[0], data[1], data[2] etc...

This is the first form where Serialport1 is found and the data arrives through the serialPort1_DataReceived event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Media;

namespace AUTOCLAVES_GUI
{
    public partial class GUI_AUTOCLAVES_GENERADOR_DE_VAPOR : Form
    {
        /*VARIABLES GLOBALES*/
        string puerto_seleccionado;

        public GUI_AUTOCLAVES_GENERADOR_DE_VAPOR()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string[] puertos = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string mostrar in puertos)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(mostrar);
            }
        }

        private void Salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Minimizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void Maximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Maximizar.Visible = false;
            Restaurar.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Restaurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Restaurar.Visible = false;
            Maximizar.Visible = true;
        }

        private void MenuSideBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Sidebar.Width == 270)
            {
                Sidebar.Visible = false;
                Sidebar.Width = 68;
                SidebarWrapper.Width = 90;
                LineaSidebar.Width = 68;
                AnimacionSidebar.Show(Sidebar);
            }

            else
            {
                Sidebar.Visible = false;
                Sidebar.Width = 270;
                SidebarWrapper.Width = 300;
                LineaSidebar.Width = 268;
                AnimacionSidebarBack.Show(Sidebar);
            }
        }

        private void bunifuFlatButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                serialPort1.Dispose();
                serialPort1.Open();
                CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                label2.Text = "CONEXIÓN EXITOSA";
                label2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label2.Font = new Font(label2.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                openChildForm(new MUESTREO_EN_TIEMPO_REAL());
            }

            catch
            {
                label2.Text = "CONEXIÓN FALLIDA";
                label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label2.Font = new Font(label2.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                MessageBox.Show("REVISE CONEXIÓN DE ARDUINO", "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            puerto_seleccionado = comboBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.PortName = puerto_seleccionado;
        }

        private void bunifuFlatButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            label2.Text = "SIN CONEXIÓN";
            label2.ForeColor = Color.White;
            string[] puertos = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string mostrar in puertos)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(mostrar);
            }
        }

        private Form activeForm = null;
        private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Controls.Add(childForm);
            panel1.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();
        }

        private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openChildForm(new MUESTREO_EN_TIEMPO_REAL());
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] data = serialPort1.ReadLine().Split(',');

            if (data.Length > 10)
            {

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Intente nuevamente", "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my second form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AUTOCLAVES_GUI 
{
    public partial class MUESTREO_EN_TIEMPO_REAL : Form
    {
        public MUESTREO_EN_TIEMPO_REAL()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MUESTREO_EN_TIEMPO_REAL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me overcome this problem.

Comment: You lost me (and probably someone else) here: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`. Then, why are you using a Form treated as a UserControl to show these values: build a UserControl and set public properties or call a public method to update its internal Controls (the same thing you could do with the Form, but...).  First thing, fix that abomination.

Comment: Use a delegate and [Control.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) instead of allowing cross thread calls.